# How to translate select options in CakePHP3

Tags: php, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

i try to code my app in multiple language. When i create my default.pot i see, that my select options will not get translated.

```
//UsersTable
<?php

class UsersTable extends Table {

    public $userRoles = ['admin' => 'Administrator', 'author' => 'Author' ...];

}


// UsersController
public function edit($userId = 0) {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->set("user", $user);
    $this->set("userRoles", $this->Users->userRoles);
}

//edit.ctp
<?php
echo $this->Form->create($user);
echo $this->Form->input("role",["type" => "select","options" => $userRoles,"label" => __("Userrole")]);
```

I tried something like this:

```
$_userRoles = [];
foreach ($userRoles as $key => $value) {
    $_userRoles[$key] = __($value); // tried also __($value, true)
}
```

but this creates an error during i18n extract.

How can i get a translation for these entries?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define options in Entity Class instead of Table Class

Make change in Entity as below

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\I18n\I18n; //important to use this

class User extends Entity {

    .....

    private $userRoles = ['admin' => 'Administrator', 'author' => 'Author' ...];

    ......

    protected function _getUserRoles() {
        $return=();
        foreach($this->userRoles as $k=>$val)
        {
            $return[$k]=__($value);
        }
        return $return;
    }

    ......
}
```

Edit method of UsersController

```
public function edit($userId = 0) {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->set("user", $user);
    $this->set("userRoles", $user->user_roles);
}
```

Your edit.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create($user);
echo $this->Form->input("role",["type" => "select","options" => $userRoles,"label" => __("Userrole")]);
```

**OR**

Add below line in table class file before class declaration\

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

class UsersTable extends Table {
```

I hope it will help to you

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your help. First method returns following error "Table "App\Model\Table\UsersTable" is not associated with "userRoles"". Just adding the line in UserTable has no effect.

Comment: Sry, my fault. there was a bad leftover in my table class. there is no error left during runtime, but when i try to extract a pot file i get "invalid marker content __($val)".